# Test if two objects are structurally equal?

Tags: java

I have a company object with different departments and employees. I have successfully serialized my object and loaded it in my program again.

Now I want to test if those two objects are structurally equal. Does java offer me a tool to compare those objects?

I should add that my object has a list filled with other objects.

Or do I have to write my own test for this?

edit:

```
class test{

public int a

}
test t = new test();
t.a = 1;

test t1 = new test();
t1.a = 1;
```

now I want to compare t and t1 if they are the same based on their values.

Comment: just check if they are the instance of the same class using `isinstance` function

Comment: What do you mean by 'structurally equal'?

Comment: Have a look at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils//api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanComparator.html

Comment: @RahulBobhate I added an example

Comment: Are you looking for a way to compare the contents of two `Serializable` objects for equality in their serial fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the `equals` method in the `Test` class as follows:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == null) {
       return false;
    }
    if (!(other instanceof Test)) {
       return false;
    }
    return this.a == ((Test) other).a;
}
```

Also: When overriding equals, you always should also always override the hashCode method. Please see this reference for why: [Why always override hashcode() if overriding equals()?](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/why-always-override-hashcode-if-overriding-equals/20)

Comment: Always override hashcode when overriding equals. This should be part of your answer. Your equals method signature is wrong. -1 until you correct this since what you recommend will not work and worse will mislead. Hint: the method parameter!

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, it can generate hashCode and equals for you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Oops. Edited it.

Comment: You still never mentioned hashCode. Why? I've added to your answer since you didn't bother doing this.

Comment: You don't need `if (x) return true else return false`, just `return x`. This helps with readability.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you can compare with overridden `equals` method I think...

Answer (score 2):

Google Guava provides [ComparisonChain](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CommonObjectUtilitiesExplained#compare/compareTo):

```
   public int compareTo(Foo that) {
     return ComparisonChain.start()
         .compare(this.aString, that.aString)
         .compare(this.anInt, that.anInt)
         .compare(this.anEnum, that.anEnum, Ordering.natural().nullsLast())
         .result();
   }
```

Apache Commons provides [CompareToBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/CompareToBuilder.html):

```
   public int compareTo(Object o) {
     MyClass myClass = (MyClass) o;
     return new CompareToBuilder()
       .appendSuper(super.compareTo(o)
       .append(this.field1, myClass.field1)
       .append(this.field2, myClass.field2)
       .append(this.field3, myClass.field3)
       .toComparison();
   }
 }
```