# this reference in a lazy initializer of kotlin extension property

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I'm trying Kotlin and want to implement a lazy extension property for Activity:

```
/**
 * Activity module
 */
val Activity.activityModule: ActivityModule by lazy {
    ActivityModule(this)
}
```

The compiler errors with:

```
'this' is not defined in this context
```

How can I qualify this as Activity this? I have read [a guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html) but can't get it. `this@Activity` says the reference is unresolved.

Comment: Can you show more code? Class declaration with this property?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, that is a top-level property. Intended to use it in Activity subclass methods to create dagger module. So it is defined in a separate file. Something like [that](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/a9109b510d362dbf133aa68d793fb1ebf1fdbd7b/dsl/static/src/common/Intents.kt)

Comment: See also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13053 with one possible workaround

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lazy` delegate in Kotlin doesn't have reference to a property member class.

I see two solutions:

1. transform it to extension function
2. implement own delegate

Answer (score 11):

Other answers here have pointed out that it is impossible to reference `this` within the stdlib's current implementation of the `lazy` receiver, and that one could implement their own delegate. So I decided to implement it and post it here...:

```
class LazyWithReceiver<This,Return>(val initializer:This.()->Return)
{
    private val values = WeakHashMap<This,Return>()

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    operator fun getValue(thisRef:Any,property:KProperty<*>):Return = synchronized(values)
    {
        thisRef as This
        return values.getOrPut(thisRef) {thisRef.initializer()}
    }
}
```

[Here is some code showing how to use it.](https://github.com/ericytsang/lib.delegates/blob/d01dce85723f65864f739944a1e90882cae19bca/src/test/kotlin/com/github/ericytsang/lib/delegates/LazyWithReceiverTest.kt)

This implementation uses a weak hash map to store a separate value for each receiver...this comes with a couple of implications...:

- distinct instances that are [structurally equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266229/test-if-two-objects-are-structurally-equal) will share the same value.
- in some cases, values that have already been initialized for some receiver could be garbage collected which means that the initializer might be called again to re-initialize the value if it is accessed again.

Answer (score 4):

`lazy` calls `initializer` function when it is accessed first time and then stores the value returned by the `initializer` to return that value on successive accesses.

An instance of `Lazy` is capable of storing exactly one value. When you delegate extension property to a `Lazy` instance, you're getting a single instance of `Lazy` serving `getValue` requests from all instances of the receiver type, in your case it's `Activity`. This results in `Lazy` computing value only for first `Activity` and using that value on all subsequent calls for other instances of `Activity`.

Therefore while it's syntactically possible to pass an `Activity` to initializer as a receiver and refer it as `this` inside as @voddan suggests in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34393382#34393382), the `Lazy` itself is not capable of storing different value for different receivers.

An ability to have an external storage for extension properties may likely be covered by "Attached properties" feature [KT-7210](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7210).
I don't think `Lazy` should have this ability as it complicates significantly its implementation.

Comment: Indeed. Didn't get it the right way. As soon as top-level is resolved statically - the only one instance will be created

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to access the `Activity` from the body of `lazy`, at least with the current signature\implementation: `fun <T> lazy(initializer: () -> T): Lazy<T>`

To do that the signature would have to look like

```
fun <A, T> lazy(initializer: A.() -> T): Lazy2<A, T>
```

You can implement such an extended function yourself, or\and report this as an issue with stdlib

Comment: What instance of type `T` would you expect should be passed as a receiver to initializer?

Comment: @Ilya I think `thisRef as T` should be the receiver: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html

Comment: So this lazy implementation would be limitied to returing values of the same type as the receiver?

Comment: Thanks guys! Anyway that does not do the trick with a top-level extension property as there is no 'this' value and 'thisRef' when defining initializer. So you come to the same result. Ended up with extension function.

Comment: @Motorro of course there is, the stdlib just needs to be rewritten. I reported your problem to the kotlin team

Comment: @voddan could you please share a link to report?

Comment: @voddan I've created a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/motorro/e650bfb3942728226bb5) with a basic implementation. It'll be great if you could comment it and point out how would you create a top-level property with initializer above.